# Rails3 sanitize escape HTML rather than remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, sanitize

Is there a way to have the ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper#sanitize method escape the offending HTML rather than just completely removing it?

I would use `h` but I need the sanitize method because you can set it to ignore certain tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in sanitize method is merely a shortcut utility, and doesn't even handle malformed markup.

Please do yourself a favor and check out http://github.com/rgrove/sanitize

You can build filters for specific tags and is highly-customizable.

Comment: This gem is much better than the built in function, but I still don't see how to escape the offending HTML rather than removing it. Now that I think about it, its probably not possible, as both of these are designed to handle attributes as well, and you can't just escape attributes.

Comment: I now see the `:transformers` option

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ruby's CGI::escapeHTML method

```
self.content = CGI::escapeHTML(self.content)
```